# Programmatically move Mac menu bar between displays

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, nsuserdefaults

I'm looking for a way to programmatically move the menu bar on a multi-display setup from one display to another.  Ideally I would do this in Objective C, but I'm open to shell scripts, AppleScript, etc.

In Objective C, I can get a pointer to the screen with the menu bar by using `[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex: 0]`.  However, I obviously cannot write to that array.

Is there an NSUserDefaults preference I can switch?  I ran `defaults read > defaults.txt` in Terminal to try to find the correct one, but it's like finding a needle in a haystack :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a command line tool I created to do that [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/hmscreens/hmscreens.html). You'll also find the source code to the tool on the web page so you can see how I did it programmatically and use that as an example for your code. Good luck.